# MySQL Array in Procedure/Function

Tags: mysql, arrays, function, mysql-workbench

I just started writing scripts in the MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE. After creating some simple functions, I was wondering if there is a way to create an array of data type Integer, so that I'm able to access every single index of it.

This is the part of my current Script:

```
drop function if exists new_function;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION new_function ()
RETURNS INTEGER

BEGIN
SET @myArrayOfValue = ('2,5,2,23,6');
RETURN ELT(1,@myArrayOfValue);
END$$

select new_function() from dual;
```

I'm getting the following error message: *Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'new_function()' at row 1*

Are there any quick fixes or data structures I'm missing? I heard about using tables instead of arrays, but I don't know how to use them in this case.

Please let me know down below. Thank you!

Comment: You may create and use JSON array.

Comment: *I'm getting the following error message:* You have not read the documentation. ELT is not applicable to single CSV string literal, it needs a list of separate literals. Formally you need the function complement to FIND_IN_SET - but the last one is SET-oriented and have no string antipode. So dual SUBSTRING_INDEx is a solution.

Comment: JSON array just worked fine for me, thanks a lot!